# How do I calculate the average of specific indexes within multiple arrays input by a user in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly or not, but here is what I did.  Ultimately I want to take user input of test results to get their average from each test and display the grade with average score and name. This is for a class assignment.

Data:

```
test1 = {67, 87, 71, 79, 100} \\I want the user to be able to input this data as test results may vary
test2 = {70, 90, 74, 82, 100}
test3 = {73, 93, 77, 85, 100}
```

Code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradesArray {

    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] nameArray = {"Jon", "Rajesh", "Elizabeth", "Julio", "Chang"};
        System.out.println("Enter the five scores from Test 1, type 0 when done");
        String[] gradeArray = new String[5];
            double[] test1Array = {reader.nextInt()};
            int keyboard = reader.nextInt();
            while (keyboard != 0){
                keyboard = reader.nextInt();
            }
        System.out.println("Enter the five scores from Test 2, type 0 when done");
            double[] test2Array = {reader.nextInt()};
            int keyboard2 = reader.nextInt();
            while (keyboard2 != 0){
                keyboard2 = reader.nextInt();
            }
        System.out.println("Enter the five scores from Test 3, type 0 when done");
            double[] test3Array = {reader.nextInt()};
            int keyboard3 = reader.nextInt();
            while (keyboard3 != 0){
            keyboard3 = reader.nextInt();
            }
            double[] averageArray = new double[5];
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ 
                averageArray[i] = (test1Array[i] + test2Array[i] + test3Array[i])/3;
                    if (averageArray[i] >=90){
                        gradeArray[i] = "A";
                    } else if (averageArray[i] >= 80){
                        gradeArray[i] = "B";
                    } else if (averageArray[i] >= 70){
                        gradeArray[i] = "C";
                    } else if (averageArray[i] >= 60){
                        gradeArray[i] = "D";
                    } else{
                        gradeArray[i] = "F";
                    }
            }
            System.out.println("Name is: " + nameArray[i] + " Grade is: " + gradeArray[i] + " Average is: " + averageArray[i]);
        }
}
```

#### Snapshot of error

[image: Snapshot of error]

Here is the original code that had intentional errors that we had to correct, but then the instructor asked us to try and rewrite the code using different classes and methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradesArray {
public static void main (String[]args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to your Grade Average Calculator");
    String[] nameArray = {"Jon", "Rajesh", "Elizabeth", "Julio", "Chang"};
    String[] gradeArray = new String[5];

    double[] score1Array = {67, 87, 71, 79, 100};
    double[] score2Array = {70, 90, 74, 82, 100};
    double[] score3Array = {73, 93, 77, 85, 100};
    double[] averageArray = new double[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ 
         averageArray[i] = (score1Array[i] + score2Array[i] + score3Array[i])/3;
    if (averageArray[i] >=90){
        gradeArray[i] = "A";
    } else if (averageArray[i] >= 80){
        gradeArray[i] = "B";
    } else if (averageArray[i] >= 70){
        gradeArray[i] = "C";
    } else if (averageArray[i] >= 60){
        gradeArray[i] = "D";
    } else{
        gradeArray[i] = "F";
    }
    System.out.println("Name is: " + nameArray[i] + " Grade is: " + gradeArray[i] + " Average is: " + averageArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `println` statement is outside (after) the loop, so `i` doesn't exist there. Move the statement up one line.

Comment: Once you do that, your code will fail because your test arrays are all length 1. Re-think what you're doing when building those arrays and loading them with data from the user.

Comment: I have posted the original code that had several intentional errors for us to correct, but then the instructor asked to try to rewrite using classes and methods.  My apologies for not explaining this as best as possible.  This is week four of my very first programming class.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? You asked about the compilation error. You got the answer for that. My second comment was just to let you know you had more to fix, beyond the problem listed in this question. And those errors are not in the "original" code you just added, so I'm not sure what the point of that comment is.

Comment: I was trying to show what was provided and what I decided to make on my own, as you pointed out, I had one piece in the wrong spot.  So thank you for that help.  I am not sure how I am supposed to rethink what I am doing; that is why I was reaching out.  The textbook provided is terrible and I have seen the great support within this community so I gave it a shot sorry if I did not explain it clearly.

Comment: Well, the problem described in the question has been addressed. If you have another problem, e.g. how to correctly prompt the user for numbers, I'd suggest you start with a web search (actually, with multiple web searches, since the first might not be good), then create another question here if you still have trouble.

Comment: @Andreas thank you for all the information.  I was able to walk away for a few and then reattack it again with what you said and I got it to work.  I moved the statement like you suggested and reworked the user input and array layout.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println("` is out of loop, i has different vale

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            averageArray[i] = (test1Array[i] + test2Array[i] + test3Array[i]) / 3;
            // rest of the code
            System.out.println("Name is: " + nameArray[i] + " Grade is: " + gradeArray[i] + " Average is: " + averageArray[i]);
        }
```